# WCF service to stream buffer frame by frame to all client

Tags: wcf, wcf-streaming

I am looking for a way to write a wcf service which stream frame by frame buffer to all client. I do not want to use soap envelops and make it possible to consume the same service from all platforms like windows, android and iPhone clients. I want to control the media stream manually. Like, in my client side form application, I can control the streaming by start and stop button. Also I want to manage all kind of error handling.

I have been googling a lot for my requirements but I ended up no where. I have considered nettcpbinding but it also uses soap envelop. Here I want persistent connection like basic tcp socket.

Comment: My requirement is duplex like behavior so I need to go with http or tcp binding. But all system provided bindings are soap based so if I want to use non-soap like structure I need to go with POX type service for custom request format. For the case of streaming I think, I have two ways to select from. One is define custom stream and return its instance from service contract and another one is callback structure. But I think callback is for notification like requirements. So I think, Custom stream will help me. Let me know whatever I am considering. Suggest me where to put effort.